# Updating from Magento 2.2.5 to 2.3.1 fails with errors

Tags: magento, magento2.2, magento-2.3

When trying to update Magento 2.2.5 to 2.3.1 either in the System upgrade panel, or from the command line we get composer errors. We suspect it's a composer.json issue, but it's for a site that is inherited so we're a little unsure of how to manage the issue

The errors from the system update panel are below

```
Check Component Dependency
We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail

Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 requires magento/magento2-base 2.3.1 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-base[2.3.1].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v2.8.38
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.9|install symfony/console v2.8.38
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.10|install symfony/console v2.8.38
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.11|install symfony/console v2.8.38
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.12|install symfony/console v2.8.38
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.4.27|install symfony/console v4.1.10|install symfony/console v4.1.11|install symfony/console v4.1.12|install symfony/console v4.1.9
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.6|install symfony/console v2.8.38|install symfony/console v3.4.27
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.5|install symfony/console v2.8.38|install symfony/console v3.4.27
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.7|install symfony/console v2.8.38|install symfony/console v3.4.27
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.1].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.8|install symfony/console v2.8.38|install symfony/console v3.4.27
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.4.26|install symfony/console v4.1.10|install symfony/console v4.1.11|install symfony/console v4.1.12|install symfony/console v4.1.5|install symfony/console v4.1.6|install symfony/console v4.1.7|install symfony/console v4.1.8|install symfony/console v4.1.9
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.2|install symfony/console v2.8.38|install symfony/console v3.4.26|install symfony/console v3.4.27
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.1|install symfony/console v2.8.38|install symfony/console v3.4.26|install symfony/console v3.4.27
- Installation request for sebastian/phpcpd 2.0.4 -> satisfiable by sebastian/phpcpd[2.0.4].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.3|install symfony/console v2.8.38|install symfony/console v3.4.26|install symfony/console v3.4.27
- sebastian/phpcpd 2.0.4 requires symfony/console ~2.7|^3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.42, v2.7.43, v2.7.44, v2.7.45, v2.7.46, v2.7.47, v2.7.48, v2.7.49, v2.7.5, v2.7.50, v2.7.51, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.5, v2.8.50, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.0].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.10].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.11].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.12].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.13].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.14].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.15].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.16].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.17].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.18].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.19].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.2].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.20].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.21].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.22].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.23].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.24].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.25].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.26].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.27].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.28].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.29].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.3].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.30].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.31].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.32].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.33].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.34].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.35].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.36].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.37].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.38].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.39].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.4].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.40].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.41].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.42].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.43].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.44].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.45].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.46].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.47].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.48].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.49].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.5].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.50].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.51].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.6].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.7].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.9].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.0].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.10].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.11].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.12].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.13].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.14].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.15].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.16].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.17].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.18].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.19].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.2].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.20].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.21].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.22].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.23].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.24].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.25].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.26].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.27].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.28].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.29].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.3].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.30].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.31].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.32].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.33].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.34].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.35].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.36].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.37].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.39].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.4].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.40].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.41].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.42].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.43].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.44].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.45].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.46].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.47].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.48].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.49].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.5].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.50].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.6].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.7].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.9].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.0].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.2].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.3].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.4].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.5].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.6].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.7].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.9].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.0].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.10].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.2].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.3].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.4].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.5].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.6].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.7].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.9].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.0].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.10].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.11].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.12].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.13].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.14].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.2].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.3].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.4].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.5].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.6].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.7].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.9].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.0].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.10].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.11].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.12].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.13].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.14].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.15].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.16].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.17].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.18].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.2].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.3].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.4].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.5].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.6].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.7].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.9].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.0].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.10].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.11].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.12].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.13].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.14].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.15].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.16].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.17].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.18].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.19].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.2].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.20].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.21].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.22].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.23].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.24].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.25].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.3].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.4].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.5].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.6].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.7].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.9].
- magento/magento2-base 2.3.1 requires symfony/console ~4.1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.4|install symfony/console v2.8.38|install symfony/console v3.4.26|install symfony/console v3.4.27
```

composer.json is below

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.5",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.5",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "ebizmarts/sagepaysuite": "1.2.6",
        "mageplaza/module-smtp": "^1.1",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.0.1",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.1.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": {
        "ebizmarts": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.ebizmarts.com"
        }
        ,
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override",
    "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
    "patches": {
        "magento/module-email" : {
            "MAGETWO-93036 This patch provides a fix for problems that merchants experience when trying to change a storefront's applied theme in Magento 2.2.4 and 2.2.5" : "patches/composer/CE-MAGETWO-93036-2018-07-02-07-06-53.patch"
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, the sagepay plugin needs updating to fix a payment error bug that we're getting and we're very much out of our depth (as the original dev left).

Comment: Still having problems?

Answer (score 0):

It's an good idea to first only require magento 2.3.1 and test if its then working. After that composer require all other modules 1 by 1 and test them again. At the end you will know which module is responsible. This will help you out a lot!!! It's an good idea to also look online at the third party modules if they have been updated in the last months. If not remove them from composer and search for alternatives. It's a big pill to swallow a upgrade!!